# Play in right pedal

Tags: pedals-flat

I have a little play with my drive side pedal . When I twist the pedal left and right, I can feel a little play. I was wondering what could be wrong?

The bike is around 3yrs old.

They're dmr v12 pedals and it's a hardtail mountain bike.
is it also normal for the drive side to develop issues first? 
The non drive side appears to be fine

Comment: What type of bike and pedal?

Comment: Is the play in the pedal itself (the pedal bearings), in the threaded connection between pedal and crank arm, or in the connection between the crank arm and the crank axle?  The first is no big deal (pedals are expendable).  The other two suggest that service is needed fairly urgently.

Answer (score 2):

What is wrong is either the pedal bearings are worn, or were not great to begin with.

As a precaution you should also check that the pedal shaft is screwed into the crank properly and tightened to appropriate torque. A loose pedal will very quickly ruin the threads in the alloy crank and necessitate crank replacement.

As mentioned in other answers the solution depend on the exact model of pedal.

Answer (score 0):

The exact model name or at least a picture of the pedal would help a lot.

With some pedals it’s possible to open the bearings, apply grease and adjust the play. With other pedals it’s at least possible to replace the bearings. Some pedals you can only throw away when the bearings are worn or develop (too much) play. A little play might be okay, especially for sealed bearings.